# C# Check Response Type in Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

In C# .NET Core 3.1 Web API project, I return a file like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReadBook(int bookId) {
    var bookService = new BookService();
    var book = bookService.getBook(bookId);
    return  PhysicalFile(bookService.AbsoluteFilePath, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

I have added some Middleware for rewinding responses (this is used for other actions that return simple JSON), like so:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ResponseRewindMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        
        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

        try
        {
            await using var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = memStream;

            await next(context);

            memStream.Position = 0;
            await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Response.Body = originalBody;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that the file can be big and I don't have a requirement to be able to rewind the body for this action specifically.  Is there a way to skip the middleware for this particiular action?  Maybe I can check the requesting action type or the response type is PhysicalFileResult before hijacking and copying it out? Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the context, you should also have access to the action descriptor.  You could try applying a custom attribute and then check for that attribute before rewinding.

Comment: @DavidL Thanks. Do you know if skipping it would be a performance improvement? From what I understand, I am copying a potentially big file in to another memory stream, is that right?

Comment: You would have to profile it although it seems like it would be a significant performance improvement.